# Redirect not work correctly to log in page after using axios to delete user token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to make my website to do 3 things:

1. After a user signs in and receives a user token from an API, I store it in sessionStorage. So if sessionStorage.getItem('userToken'), the user will be redirected to home page.
2. If user is signed in, the user is not allowed to go back to the log in page to sign in again. So if the user try to go to /login, he will be redirected to the home page.
3. If the user logs out, his token will be deleted from sessionStorage and he will be redirected to the log in page.

If I don't use axios in my header.js to log out, it works, but if I put the sessionStorage.removeItem("userToken") inside axios, it does not work.The user will be redirected to the home page if they click logout in the header, only if I refresh page then they'll be redirected to the log in page.

So I feel the problem is:
Only when I get delete successful response from backend, the then part sessionStorage.removeItem will be executed. But only when removeItem executed, the page will be redirected because of the PrivateRoute part, so I feel the delete=> removeItem is async, and removeItem => PrivateRoute part are sync, but somehow in loginpage, because of the if (sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')) { return () } , it still can get the userToken so it still redirect to home

How can I fix it? Thank you so much!

header.js

```
logout = () => {


        const auth = sessionStorage.getItem('userToken');
        const url = `http://xxxxxx/users/sign_out`;
        // sessionStorage.removeItem("userToken"); This works..
        axios.delete(url, {
            params: { id: auth }
        }).then(res => {
            sessionStorage.removeItem("userToken");//This not work


        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);

        })
```

signIn.js

```
 constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            redirect: false

        };
    }
......

render() {

        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return (<Redirect to={'/'} />)
        }

        if (sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')) {
            return (<Redirect to={'/'} />)
        }
        return (
    <Formik
onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                                setSubmitting(true);
                                axios.post('xxx/users/sign_in', {
                                    user: {
                                        email: values.email,
                                        password: values.password
                                    }
                                }).then(res => {


                                    sessionStorage.setItem('userToken', res.data.auth_token);

                                    this.setState({ redirect: true });
                                }).catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    alert('wrong email address or password');
                                    setSubmitting(false);
                                })

                            }}

......
......
)}
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        sessionStorage.getItem('userToken') ? <><Header /> <Component {...props} /></> : <Redirect to="/sign-in" />
    )} />
)
```

app.js

```
<Switch>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}>
            </PrivateRoute>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/management" component={Management}>
            </PrivateRoute>




            <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUpForm}>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/sign-in" component={SignInForm}>
            </Route>

            <Route component={Error}>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because putting `sessionStorage.removeItem("userToken");` inside axios callback is async and putting `sessionStorage.removeItem("userToken");`directly in the logout method is synchronous.

So the moment user is redirected to the home page after clicking logout, the `userToken` is still present the sessionStorage. Because the callback function of axios haven't executed yet, it's still waiting for the response of the callback function.

To fix this, try redirecting to homepage in the axios callback function itself. This makes sure that when the user arrives on homepage the `userToken` is removed from the session storage.

Comment: Thank you so much! I put sessionStorage.removeItem("userToken") at the then part of axios, so I feel it's like after I get the res from the backend without error, it will run sessionStorage.removeItem("userToken") , may I know why is it async? I 'm still confused. Also if I remove if (sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')) {
             return (<Redirect to={'/'} />)
        } it will work for the logout, but won't able to prevent logged in user to go back to log in page again

Comment: I wonder if there is any time problem between the header logout remove sessionStorage inside async axios and the log in page using sessionStorage.getItem... May I know how to fix it?

Comment: 1. The axios `then` part is async because it's only executed after delete request has returned. Please read [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-through-household-chores-e3de9a1dbd04/](this) article to understand asynchronous concept better.  
2. To prevent signed in user to go back to login page, what you can do is, in `componentDidMount` of the login page check if userToken exists in sessionStorage,if it doesn't exist do nothing but if it does exists redirect to homepage.

Comment: And no there's no such time problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I put if (sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')) {
           return (<Redirect to={'/'} />)
        } in  componentDidMount method but it does not work. It does work in render method, but cause the logout problem again.

Comment: So I was thinking that only when I get delete successful response from backend, the then part sessionStorage.removeItem  will be executed. But only when removeItem executed, the page will be redirected because of the PrivateRoute part, so I feel the delete=> removeItem is async, and removeItem => PrivateRoute part are sync, but somehow in loginpage, because of the  if (sessionStorage.getItem('userToken')) { return (<Redirect to={'/'} />) } , it still can get the userToken so it still redirect to home

Comment: You can't use `<Redirect to={'/'} />` in `componentDidMount`, you can do that only in `render`. Please use `this.props.history.push('/')` in componentDidMount instead.

Comment: Also, refer ['https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/'](this) blog if you want to redirect using `<Redirect/>`

Comment: Hi @Ying if you find my answer helpful, pl accept/upvote.